# How can you define a function with variables and put it equal to a function that is already defined?

Tags: variable-definitions

Lets say you have a function:

```
f = x^2 + y^2
```

Now I want to define a new function of `x` and `y` like this:

```
g(x_, y_):=2*f
```

`g(1, 1)` now gives no output. How can I fix this (get 4 as output)?

Comment: Please have a look at the [tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DefiningFunctions.html).

Comment: See also [`The Four Kinds of Bracketing in the Wolfram Language`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TheFourKindsOfBracketingInTheWolframLanguage.html)

Comment: If `f`is a *function* making this more explicit almost always is a good idea: Either `f = Function[ ... ]` or `f[ x_, y_ ] := some expression using x and y`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Set` instead of `SetDelayed`.

```
Clear[f, g, x, y]
f = x^2 + y^2  
g[x_, y_] = 2*f
g[1, 1]  (* 4 *)
```

Check that this worked:

```
DownValues[g]  (* {HoldPattern[g[x_,y_]]:>2 (x^2+y^2)} *)
```

Comment: or use `g[x_, y_] := Evaluate[2*f]`

Answer (score 0):

You have some syntax issues in your code. For one, `g(x_,y_)` should be `g[x_,y_]`. Calling `g` would be done by `g[1,1]` rather than `g(1,1)`.

There are at least two ways to do what you're looking for.

First is to make `f` a function that takes `x` and `y` as arguments:

```
f[x_, y_] := x^2 + y^2
g[x1_, y1_] := 2*f[x1, y1]
```

Now `g[1,1]` returns 4.

Another way is to use `Replace` (`/.`):

```
f = x^2 + y^2
g[x1_, y1_] := 2*(f /. {x -> x1, y -> y1})
```